# Trigger an event on a raspi behind a firewall

Tags: python, email, raspberry-pi

I have a raspi which monitors solar panels on my roof. It is installed behind a firewall.

I can send emails from that raspi (e.g. in case of errors).

Now I want to be able to get an email reporting the actual status at the moment whenever I am interested, triggering this by an email from my mobile.

The only solution I can think of is sending an email from my mobile to an email account which is checked regularily by the raspberry, using code such as:

http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-physical-gmail-notifier/

Are there any other methods (also other than email) which I have not thought of? I don't think that there is a way to do that without active polling from the raspi.

If I have to use active polling (e.g. every minute or so), are there other methods than email which generate less permanent traffic?

I am aware that this question may be borderline for stackoverflow, since I am looking for a concept or a hint to functions rather than an actual problem in my code, and apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use cloud-based log management and analysis. Some of them are free for very limited features (usually on log retention or amount of notifications).